# Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine on Ubuntu

Tags: docker

I am running Docker on a Ubuntu server:

Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

Docker was running without problems for a year or so but suddenly it is not available anymore:

```
root@srv-lab-t-427:/home/schm# systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2023-02-05 06:43:29 UTC; 2min 43s ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 1478999 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/>
   Main PID: 1478999 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 05 06:43:29 srv-lab-t-427 systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Feb 05 06:43:29 srv-lab-t-427 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Feb 05 06:43:29 srv-lab-t-427 systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 05 06:43:29 srv-lab-t-427 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 05 06:43:29 srv-lab-t-427 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked if the docker engine got upgraded? 
Also can you check the docker daemon logs?

Comment: Yes, it has been upgraded: $ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           23.0.0
 API version:       1.42
 Go version:        go1.19.5
 Git commit:        e92dd87
 Built:             Wed Feb  1 17:49:08 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Comment: I have also found the docker daemon logs, the problem occured yesterday but I don't know how to fix this:

Comment: ```Feb 04 ... " level=error msg="Failed to get event" error="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
... level=error msg="Failed to get event" error="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
Feb 04 23:07:28 srv-lab-t-427 dockerd[1861102]: ...Err :connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock: timeout\". Err :connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock: timeout\"```

Comment: ```Reconnecting..." module=grpc
Feb 04 23:07:34 srv-lab-t-427 systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Application Container Engine...
-- Subject: A stop job for unit docker.service has begun execution... -- The unit docker.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Feb 04 23:07:37 srv-lab-t-427 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.```

Comment: Have you tried to restart the daemon? `sudo service docker restart`

Comment: Yes, I have tried to restart the daemon already but it quits with an error message: ```service docker restart
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.```

Comment: I have run apt-get update, apt-get upgrade and it turns out that there is one package that is not fully installed:
```After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up docker-ce (5:23.0.0-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal) ...
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "restart" failed.```

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the docker daemon logs: `journalctl -xu docker.service`

I found this error message after the upgrade:

> unable to configure the Docker daemon with file
> /etc/docker/daemon.json: merged configuration validation from file and
> command line flags failed: the "graph" config file option is
> deprecated; use "data-root" instead

Just simply change `graph` to `data-root` to resolve this issue.

Comment: So simple... just read the error message :) Didn't do  that. Came to this answer. Thank you!